# Short story about creating a window out of thread wire and seeing dogs outlive humanity

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I need help locating a short story about the creation of a dimensional/temporal window using wire.

The way I remember the "window" is like those arts and crafts made using wire and nails to create drawings, but in this case the creation of the window happens due to the complex pattern the wires are arranged.

The observer sees many things, but I only remember he seeing dogs outliving humanity until they evolve and leave using a portal.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  (Was it in an anthology, a magazine or online?)  Do you remember anything else related to this story (art, other stories read in the same work, etc.)?

Comment: The part about dogs strongly resembles parts of *City* -- a makeup novel from several short stories by Clifford Simak.  However, that didn't, as far as I recall, have anything about weaving a temporal or dimensional window with a complex pattern of wires.

Comment: Hi! I dont remember well, it was years ago. I would guess it was in an anthology. Probably listed as science-fiction.

Comment: In terms of the "wire and nails", are you asking about the [bezier curve](https://plus.maths.org/content/bridges-string-art-and-bezier-curves) kind where a "curve" is built out of a set of shifting straight lines.